# How to Allow WhatsApp Live Voice / Video Call on Router Parental Control

Tags: facebook, wifi, router, voip

I using Tp-link Router TL-WR940N.
**So first i tell you How Tp-link Router TL-WR940N Parental Control Works..!**

Tp-link Router TL-WR940N Parental control menu has only to allow websites option by keywords, it doesn't have block option by keywords. So I can add sites by domain keywords to allow access to those websites which I want to give access to my WiFi users and rest of all websites will be automatically blocked by router.

For example I add following domain keywords to allow access to following sites/apps for my WiFi users, it works perfectly and allow only these apps/sitesm and WiFi users can't go any other website except these.

For google I use this keyword and it allow all Google subdomains and TLDs

```
google                 <=== Router accept this keyword like this *.google.*
```

for Facebook I use these keywords and it allow all Facebook

```
facebook                <=== Router accept this keyword like this *.facebook.*
fbcdn                     <=== Router accept this keyword like this *.fbcdn.*
messenger             <=== Router accept this keyword like this *.messenger.*
msngr                    <=== Router accept this keyword like this *.msngr.*
```

for YouTube I use these keywords and it allow all YouTube

```
youtube                       <=== Router accept this keyword like this *.google.*
ytimg                           <=== Router accept this keyword like this *.ytimg.*
ggpht                           <=== Router accept this keyword like this *.ggpht.*  
googlevideo                 <=== Router accept this keyword like this *.googlevideo.*
```

Like I simply add **google** keyword and it will allow anything before dot and after dot of domain keyword,  and router automatically allow access to all subdomains before and TLD domain extensions after keyword, for example if I add keyword  **facebook**  in Parental Control, then Router assume it like this anything.facebook.anytld or like this * .facebook.*

**Now come to the problem:**

**So the problem is start when I try to allow WhatsApp on router Parental Control,**  it won't works on WhatsApp Live Voice calls and Video Calls, However I added these hostname keywords for WhatsApp:

```
whatsapp
whatsapp-plus
whatsappbrand
whatsapp-plus
wa
meta
facebook
fb
fbcdn
```

But on above domain keywords it still not allow Live Audio and Video calls on WhatsApp. However it rings the phone but when I pickedup the call I hear no voice or see no video on both sides  incoming or outgoing. and it **shows Connecting**.

**But I can send text and voice messages and images perfectly in both offline or online mode.** So it means above hostname keywords are **allow** to send text and voice messages on WhatsApp **but not allowing** live voice calls or video calls on WhatsApp.

I think for Live/Realtime voice and video calls WhatsApp using some other hostnames for sending data. So anyone please resolve this issue and tell me what other **domains/ hostnames** used by WhatsApp for live voice or video calls so I will add those domains to my Parentrol control section to allow them. Like when you make Live video or voice calls from WhatsApp then during this procedure which domains/hostnames are used by WhatsApp for sending voice/video data.

Here is some links to Guide,  How TP-Link router Parental Control Works:

[Guide to TP-Link Router Parental Control](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/350/)

[Video Guide to TP-Link Router Parental Control](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHwtkMDYEio)